# What does Q_D macro do in Qt

Tags: qt, macros

I am exploring Qt source code and came across this `Q_D` macro. Could some one please explain what it does?

Almost all the time it should return a widget of the type given as a parameter which is the `d` variable. Need more clarification on this.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In short, Qt uses private implementation to manage data. For classes that do this, there usually is an X class and an XPrivate class. The Q_D macro defines the "d" pointer so if you write d->whatever, you have access to that private data part.

This article should pretty much cover most of your questions:

https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer

Answer (score 21):

Q_D is part of Qt's implementation of d-pointers, or the pimpl pattern (private implementation). A bit more information on all of this can be found on the Qt DevNet wiki: https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer

Comment: Thanks, @HeyYO ! Fixed now; better late than never? :)

Comment: Useful link, exactly what  I needed to know.